# How do I use the ddply function on R?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a function that gives me the summary statistics of earthquakes for a certain year:

I have data on earthquakes from years 1900-2007. How do I use the `ddply` function to give me the summary statistics from all years? I am running this but it doesnt do anything.

```
allmags <- ddply(.data = quakes, .variables = year, .fun = quake_summary)
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to use `plyr::ddply` any more.  The modern thing is to use `dplyr`.  Something like `quakes %>% group_by_(~ year) %>% summarize_(MaxMagnitude = ~ max(magnitude))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
allmags <- ddply(quakes, .(year), function(x) summary(x))
```